# What are some effective strategies to track down native memory leaks in a node.js process?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I've been trying to track down a very slow, but persistent, native memory leak in a node.js app, and I've run out of strategies.

The process has what appears to be a level heap, but as the hours and days roll on, the RSS of the node.js process slowly grows. The process is a job handler that runs the same type of job for different parameters, over and over. The growth of the RSS of the process takes the same shape as the line plotting the cumulative number of jobs run, so each job run is somehow leaking a bit of memory.

Since the heap is more or less constant, the standard heap inspection tools don't seem to be much help.

Here's an example of what the memory consumption looks like:

[image: Memory usage over a few days]

Currently running on node 0.8.7. Each job does a number of database reads/writes, communicates with a redis instance, and does some web requests using mikael/request.

Comment: Here are some good tutorials and articles on troubleshooting memory leaks in node.


https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/
https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had already read through those before posting this. They're helpful for finding cases where v8 objects are being leaked on the heap, but that doesn't seem to be the case here, as the heap usage is basically constant over days, but the RSS usage slowly builds up.

Comment: its awesome that you are using graphite :) if its your first time using it, you will be happy with the visibility it gives you into your production systems.

Answer (score 2):

### Have you updated to the newest release?

I know everyone says that :), I just felt like I should join the band wagon of updating my version of node.js on my production servers every two weeks when I think I have an issue. Sounds like a great idea doesn't it?

So I have been wondering the same thing, I have several node.js projects that I have been managing for a few months now (and also that I wrote last year). It seems that very slowly the V8 engine, or my node application, just eats memory and never frees it. (its slow enough that I only have to restart them every now and then)

Which is very stressful, especially considering that it should free up the RSS memory, or eventually peak out.

**If you are interested in tracking objects being leaked inside of the runtime** (and by that i mean javascript objects, functions, etc), mozilla has a very [complete blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/) about tracking down memory leaks and a few links to projects that can be used to do this.

For what ever reason they don't have this one on the list though. (it seems simple enough, I'm trying it out now on my own projects to see if it works, I tend to not get any of the V8 based ones to compile correctly)

[heapdump](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump) and [here is a link to a how to guide](http://jpallen.net/2013/03/08/tracking-down-a-memory-leak-in-node-js-and-socket-io/).

---

From my own experience the V8 engine seems to allocate memory, and hold onto it just incase it needs that exact same memory chunk later. Also my brother who has been using Node.js heavily for about 3 years has seen the same thing.

Also just for completeness (I know you already have), **if any one would like to verify that you are not leaking memory inside of V8**, an engineer from joyent has a pretty decent write up of [how to track V8 memory leaks down](http://www.joyent.com/blog/bruning-questions-where-s-my-memory-going).